# Spring Boot 3 After add OpenAPI dependency NoProviderFoundException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, openapi, spring-boot-maven-plugin

> Exception :-
>
> jakarta.validation.NoProviderFoundException: Unable to create a
> Configuration, because no Jakarta Bean Validation provider could be
> found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
> at
> jakarta.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:291)
> ~[jakarta.validation-api-3.0.2.jar:na] at
> jakarta.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:103)
> ~[jakarta.validation-api-3.0.2.jar:na] at
> org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:479)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final] at
> org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.activate(TypeSafeActivator.java:82)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final] at
> ......
>
> ....org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
> ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2] at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302)
> ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2] at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291)
> ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2] at
> com.spring.security.MicroServiceServer1Application.main(MicroServiceServer1Application.java:10)
> ~[classes/:na] at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) ~[na:na] at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> ~[na:na] at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:na] at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
> at
> org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
> ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:137)

Maven Dependency :-

```xml
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
 ...
```

I have to Document my apis so i added the OpenAPI and my Spring boot project is Spring Boot 3.
so I added and It's throwing a NoProviderFoundException but OpenAPI Works fine but I can't understand why it's come so i search so many time in every where but I doesn't get my answer so.

Please any one have knowledge then please reply.

And

I have Added Jakarta Validation Also but still exception coming

dependency :-

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

*** Thank You ***

Answer (score 7):

Instead of adding `jakarta.validation-api` as dependency, try `spring-boot-starter-validation`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Works well, I don't know why this is not mentioned in the [official doc](https://springdoc.org/#getting-started).

Comment: not working after adding :
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>

but still seeing same issue